# Variables won't increment in a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, increment

I was just doing some last minute touches when I came across a problem with my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
/* Declaring some variables to help with scrolling through my Portfolio */
var workArray = [];
var scrollPos = 1;

/* This makes the left scroll arrow disappear if it's 
at the start (scrollPos is less then or equal to 1) */
if (scrollPos <= 1) {
    $('#left_scroll').hide();
} else {
    $('#left_scroll').show();
}

/*This SHOULD decrement and increment values to the scrollPos variable
when the corresponding arrows are clicked*/ 
$('#left_scroll').click(function(){
    scrollPos--;
});
$('#right_scroll').click(function(){
    scrollPos++;
});
```

(left_scroll) is assigned to an arrow key on my page that is suppose to subtract from the value (scrollPos) that tells when the left or right arrow image should be visible.

Currently I have the value scrollPos set to 1, so the left arrow key is invisible and the right one is visible, but for some reason, when either one is clicked it doesn't appear as though any values are changed as the left arrow key remains invisible.

Can anyone see any problems with my code, hope you can help. :D

- Martin

Comment: Only problem I currently see is the missing close bracket of the document-ready function block. But that might have gotten lost when you pasted your code... How does your HTML code look? Do your buttons even trigger at all (e.g. tested with `alert`)? Any jsFiddle link?

Comment: Oh no I've only posted a small portion of the JS code, it's there just I haven't posted it.

Answer (score 2):

The click handlers are just doing what you told them to do, and that is increment and decrement. You didn't tell the handlers to do anything else, like some `hide` and `show`.

Place the logic inside for `hide` and `show` inside the handler functions in order to hide and show on clicking your buttons.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean?, I'm very new to jQuery still

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A4fwj/2/)**

You must call your `if` statement after your increment/decrement.
Make a function for this:

```
function checkScrollPos() {
    /* This makes the left scroll arrow disappear if it's 
    at the start (scrollPos is less then or equal to 1) */
    if (scrollPos <= 1) {
        $('#left_scroll').hide();
    } else {
        $('#left_scroll').show();
    }
}
```

And after your `click`, call it:

```
$('#left_scroll').click(function(){
    scrollPos--;
    checkScrollPos();
});
$('#right_scroll').click(function(){
    scrollPos++;
    checkScrollPos();
});
```

Comment: Ah wonderful, totally forgot about functions, much appreciated mate!

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
if (scrollPos <= 1) {
    $('#left_scroll').hide();
} else {
    $('#left_scroll').show();
}
```

Only executes one time. If you want to check `scrollPos` value every time your arrows get clicked, use a function:

```
function hideOrShow(scrollPos) {    
    if (scrollPos <= 1) {
        $('#left_scroll').hide();
    } else {
        $('#left_scroll').show();
    }
}

$('#left_scroll').click(function(){
    scrollPos--;
    hideOrShow(scrollPos)
});
$('#right_scroll').click(function(){
    scrollPos++;
    hideOrShow(scrollPos)
});
```